# Hide file started through 'run' key in registry

Tags: batch-file, window, registry, hide

I have created a run key in the registry for a simple batch file which copies the ip of a server I play COD on to the clipboard, so I don't have to open my browser to get it.

However, every time I log on, it displays the annoying CMD which does the copying.

Is there a way to hide the program started via Registry, so it doesn't show up unless task manager is opened? I prefer this as a solution as opposed to another method.

Thanks

Comment: You can do this using a VBScript to launch the .bat file hidden.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a vbs file to launch a batch file with the window hidden so that it is only visible in task manager.

Visit: http://www.instructables.com/id/Start-a-batch-file-completely-hidden/ for a brief instructable.

The code is basically:

```
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run """" & "C:\batch-file.bat" & """", 0, False
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compile it with a program called "advanced bat to exe". Google it, it's free.

Once you compile the script, there is an option that says "launch invisible".  This is what you want.

I think this is the best method, as there's only one file. It's also probably the easiest.